# Changing a rectangular equation into polar equation

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Find the polar equation that has the same graph as the given rectangular equation. I have used the method of substituting $r \sin θ$ for $y$ and $r\cos θ$ for $x$.

$x^2=8(2−y)$

$r^2\cos^2(θ)=8(2−r\sin θ)$

$r^2(1−\sin^2θ)=16−8r\sin θ$

$r^2=r^2\sin^2θ−8r\sin θ+16$

Would be taking the perfect square of the right side of this problem take me to 
the answer?

Comment: Fix your notations please. There's an $=$ missing in the first line :)

Comment: A quick way to find out is to try it.

Comment: From your third equation you should subtract the terms on the right from both sides giving a quadratic equation in $r$ which you can then solve for $r$.

Comment: I got plus or minus $(rsin\theta-4)^2$. I'm not sure if there are supposed to be 2 answers.

Comment: If you write out the expansion of $(r \sin\theta-4)^2$ on a clean sheet of paper and then compare it to what you wrote before, I think you'll find you don't need the $\pm$ sign. But if you try to take the _square roots_ of two things that are equal--for example to remove the "squaring" on both sides--you often do need to introduce a $\pm$ sign. (In this case, perversely, it seems that it still doesn't matter in the end.)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
x^2=8(2-y)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
r^2\cos^2\theta=16-8r\sin\theta
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
r^2\cos^2\theta+8r\sin\theta-16=0
\end{equation}
Applying the quadratic formula and simplifying gives
\begin{equation}
r=\frac{4}{\sin\theta\pm1}
\end{equation}
But both
\begin{equation}
r=\frac{4}{\sin\theta+1}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
r=\frac{4}{\sin\theta-1}
\end{equation}
give the entire parabola, so either is correct. You do not need both.

[graph](http://fooplot.com/plot/7yi8os6t41)